# Force reauthorization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Had no luck in finding this but I would like to recheck a user by forcing them to login again before proceeding to a view or POST of a view. How would I accomplish this?

The background is that this user is an Admin (Admin Role) and there are some admin functions I would like protected in terms of forcing them to enter their password in again before the function can be executed. One of the functions is to reset the data so basically would like a check beforehand.

Comment: you want to redirect users to login?, so they cant use anything unless they are logged in?

Comment: They are already logged in, I just want to recheck login for sensitive functions such as resetting data. I want to do this because if the Admin is logged in and walks away from their machine someone can just execute that function without it being challenged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a session timeout or Authentication timeout, so you can make time , for example if the admin is away for 10 mins or something, it will logout because the session ends, but the default time of the session is 20 mins.

I found this for authentication timeout and also called Owin authentication, you should have something like this on your `StartUp.cs` file within the `App_Start` folder:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        // here you go
        ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(60000000000)
    });
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
}
```

or check here [for the session timeout](https://forums.asp.net/t/2041070.aspx?Redirect%20to%20login%20Page%20after%20session%20timeout%20in%20MVC%205)

Comment: The OP needs to re-authenticate even though the user is already logged in, as far as I understand.

Comment: yeah , now i understood after he replied in the comment @PrashanthBenny

Answer (score 0):

Just ask for a parallel authentication during post.

Regardless of weather the user is logged in or not, you could include the UserName and Password (or whatever the auth credentials are) in the form that you are posting. Just before the post, get the credentials, add to the form and post.

This way, you could validate the user in the action method itself. if credentials are wrong, you could abort the function and return an error.

Show the credential fields(like in a bootstrap modal or so) only when the post is initiated. you could use jQuery to accomplish this.

---

**Edit:**

Here, we are not using any of the contents in the cookie. or any previously stored location.
We make the user enter the UN, password **once again** in the form, Verify the now collected credentials with the authorize method, if they match, proceed.

Let me explain the scenario further.

We have a form that needs to edit the e-mail.

**so, our form will be :**

```
//The form includes fields for Username and password without which, you could bring in form validation error.

<form>
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name"><br>
  Email: <input type="text" name="Email"><br>
  UserName: <input type="text" name="UserName"><br>
  Password: <input type="password" name="Password"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**and the action is:**

```
public ActionResult EditUser(string Name, string Email, string UserName, string Password)
{
    if(AutorizeLogin(UserName,Password)) //The Login function which returns bool(The function used for login)
    {
        var User = DBContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.UserName == UserName);
        User.Name = Name; //Edit the values
        User.Email = Email;
        DBContext.SaveChanges(); //Save changes to database
    }
    else
    {
        //throw error
    }
}
```

Even if the user is logged in, without the UN and Pwd, he is not authorized to change the Email or name.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Instead of creating effectively another login screen I think it maybe possible to reuse the normal login. AccountController has a Login with a parameter of returnurl. So if i call Login with the returnurl of the functions view should that not work?

Comment: its not necessarily another login page..... **you could use the Same function in the Account Controller in your action.** just need the credentials

Comment: without even going to the login page.

Comment: Hi just had a chance to look at this again. I would still like the user to re-enter their password. Not sure if i've misunderstood but your way you are just using the existing credentials already used to login previously and therefore the user does not have to reenter their password? Which means you are not exactly checking credentials again.

Comment: just using the existing credentials already used to login previously... are you talking about autofill? or you want a password 2?

Comment: Essentially I would like the user to enter their own password again even though they are logged in already. So on calling or just before the function the user must enter their own password before it can be executed. This is to prevent executing of the function if the user has left their computer for a few minutes but are still logged in. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @SliderUK I have edited the answer with a little more details.